# Solr: Search with 'hypens' / dashes returns zero results

Tags: solr

I have various text fields and sometimes their values have hypens/dashes in them, e.g. Omega-3. Now when I search for 'Omega' or even 'Omega-', I get back relevant results but when I search for 'Omega-3' i get zero results.

Will setting catenateAll=1 in 'WordDelimiterFilterFactory' fix this issue? If yes then should I set it to 1 at both: query time and index time? Or is there anything else I need to do to fix this problem? Thanks!

Following is the portion of schema that defines the text field types .

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />

            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />

            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant query URL and which query parser is handling it. This is farfetched, but if Dismax is handling it , '-3' would mean "'3' is prohibited from the results" :-) Farfetched scenarios aside, the dashes may be *breaking* the syntax: there is character escaping at [URL level](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) and [solr level](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping+Special+Characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dashes are special characters in Solr/Lucene.  You need to escape them with a \

[Lucene Escape Characters Documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters)

Answer (score 0):

I think a slightly more applicable link is:

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook (See Intra-Word Delimiters)

There is quite a bit of advice including different approaches.